# How to set forceAuthn as true in webssoprofileoption?

Tags: java, spring-boot, saml

I'm new to Spring-boot, and have just got SAML authentication with Spring Security and Okta working following this tutorial. I am unable to set ForceAuthN under WebSSOProfileOptions, while configuring using WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.

Could someone give me an example or point me in the right direction?

I try below code but getting type error, please help how to solve it

```
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

 @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/saml*").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and() 
            .apply(saml())
                .serviceProvider()
                    .keyStore()
                        .storeFilePath("saml/keystore.jks")
                        .password(this.password)
                        .keyname(this.keyAlias)
                        .keyPassword(this.password)
                    .and()
                    .protocol("https")
                    .hostname(String.format("%s:%s", "localhost", this.port))
                    .basePath("/")
                .and()
                .identityProvider()
                    .metadataFilePath(this.metadataUrl)
                .and()
                .WebSSOProfileOptions(getWebSSOProfileOptions());

    }
 @Bean
    public WebSSOProfileOptions getWebSSOProfileOptions() {
        WebSSOProfileOptions profile = new WebSSOProfileOptions();
        profile.setForceAuthN(true);
        return profile;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to instantiate a SAMLEntryPoint and configure its defaultProfileOptions property with your WebSSOProfileOptions bean.

```
samlEntryPoint.setDefaultProfileOptions(getWebSSOProfileOptions());
```